# Sending Gmail From Myself To Myself

Tags: python

```
import smtplib
import datetime as dt


MY_EMAIL = "sendmyself123@gmail.com"
MY_PASSWORD = ("awfzhgujkjihurwm")

now = dt.datetime.now()
weekday = now.weekday()
if weekday == 3:
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(MY_EMAIL, MY_PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
            to_addrs=MY_EMAIL,
            msg = f"Subject:Hello World\n\n Hello World!"
```

Hi everyone, ı'm trying to create a program that sends email from myself to myself. although it does not give an error, it does not work. could someone help me

Comment: Today's week day is `1`, have you checked whether you're going in the `if` block? Also, gmail probably doesn't accept username/password login from libraries, you most likely need a token.